# I want to add a space in between a string in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsstring

```
- (IBAction)addSpace:(id)sender {
//here noSpce is a textbox in which i will enter some value
    NSString *one=self.noSpace.text;

    if (one.length==4)
    //if the length of the string is equal to four then it should put a whitespace 
    //in between the string.
    {
        NSString *blank=@"  ";
        NSString *two=[blank. stringByAppendingString:one,index(2)];
        NSString *new=two;


 //here withSpace is another textbox in which i want to show the expected result
            self.withSpace.text=new;
        }

//this really does not work for me
```

Comment: what is your noSpace value? and also your code formatting is very bad. Use a separate line for each code statement.

Comment: You'd better give us an example to show what do you want.

Comment: supporting @KudoCC comment, can you please update your question with an example, showing exactly what you want?

Comment: - (IBAction)addSpace:(id)sender
{
//here noSpace is a textBox 
    NSMutableString *string1=[NSMutableString stringWithString:self.noSpace.text];
    //this was what i was looking for. . . 
    [string1 insertString:@" " atIndex:2];
    //showing result of noSpace textBox in withSpace textBox.
    self.withSpace.text=string1;
    
}

Comment: Do you want display space or do you want to insert a particular whitespace character?

Comment: i wanted to add a whitespace, i have done this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> NSString *two=[blank. stringByAppendingString:one,index(2)];

There's an extraneous `.` after `blank` in the method call. Remove that and the `index(2)` and your code should work better.

Your code would be improved by using a mutable string. You could use `-insertString:atIndex:` and avoid the need for all those intermediate strings.

**Update:** You should also change the name of your `new` variable. `new` is the name of a method in NSObject, and also a reserved word in C++. Using it as a variable name should work, but it's bound to lead to confusion in the future.

Comment: I want to put a whitespace in between a string, if the length of the string is equal to 4 then it should put a blank space in between the string.

Comment: - (IBAction)addSpace:(id)sender
{
//here noSpace is a textBox 
    NSMutableString *string1=[NSMutableString stringWithString:self.noSpace.text];
    //this was what i was looking for. . . 
    [string1 insertString:@" " atIndex:2];
    //showing result of noSpace textBox in withSpace textBox.
    self.withSpace.text=string1;
    
}

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)addSpace:(id)sender
{
//here noSpace is a textBox 
    NSMutableString *string1=[NSMutableString stringWithString:self.noSpace.text];
    //this was what i was looking for. . . 
    [string1 insertString:@" " atIndex:2];
    //showing result of noSpace textBox in withSpace textBox.
    self.withSpace.text=string1;

}
```